# Grouping array values in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with some value like this:

```
[Organization_id] => Array
  (
     [0] => 4
     [1] => 4
     [2] => 4
  )
```

but i want some thing like this:

```
[Organization_id] => Array
  (
     [0] => 4
  )
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't care about the key to value association possibly messing up, you can use this:

```
$array = array_unique($array);
```

Answer (score 4):

Although [array_unique](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) was mentioned twice now, I feel the answers failed to point out that you have to use the function on the nested array and not the array itself, so here is a usage example

```
$array = array( 'Organization_id' => array(4,4,4) );
$array['Organization_id'] = array_unique( $array['Organization_id'] );
print_r($array);
```

which will do what you want.